# In Dynamics CRM, how much of a non null, predictable-format identifier is really "domainname"?

Tags: active-directory, dynamics-crm

I have code that calls the Dynamics CRM Web API to get information about a Dynamics user. It doesn't know the user's internal Dynamics identifier ahead of time and thus relies on their Active Directory login as a key in queries.

I have a few doubts and questions about that :

- domainname (i.e. user login) is a mandatory field when you create a user in Dynamics, but will it always be non-empty - even when you disable the user for instance?
- I noticed that you can indifferently specify a login in the form `domain\username` and `username@fulldomainname` at user creation. Login seems to be kept intact inside Dynamics, so when you use the API you must be aware of the format it was entered in in the first place. For instance, searching for `mydomain\bob` won't give you a `bob@mydomain` user.

  Are there any other possible formats for a user's login in Dynamics CRM or are we safe assuming that it will follow one of these 2 patterns?
- Is domainname case-sensitive?
- How do Dynamics modules or third party tools that somehow only have windows logins to start with manage to find users deterministically? For instance, we could have an external application that needs to access all the Leads owned by a particular user in Dynamics. Do they systematically try all different login formats and all combinations of cases? I think it would be pretty spooky.

Answer (score 3):

- The attribute `domainname` will not be emptied on disabling the user - this will only affect the state of the record.
- It's true that you have to consider both variants if your authentication authority allows both variants (see last point) when using `domainname` as a query criteria.
  I could not think of a real world 3rd variation that allows omitting the domain name.
- The domain name is not case-sensitive.
- Since there are basically 2 (real world) options for on-premise systems, it's not that spooky after all: You can either authenticate against IIS directly or SSO via STS/ADFS. Both impose the accepted login and use common windows authentication methods.
  There's nothing special CRM needs to handle - it relies on users arriving with a valid authentication token.

Comment: Thank you. To be perfectly clear, the way the user authenticates isn't really part of my equation. I'm not talking about a normal use of Dynamics where we reason about the user currently logged in. I'm talking about third party applications or plugins talking to Dynamics either via the web API or the SDK/WCF endpoint in order to access *any user's* data.

Comment: For such third party modules, would you recommend using an additional surrogate unique key stored as a custom field in User records, or do you still think `domainname` is the right identifier to use despite the alternate format problems?

Comment: I would indeed recommend a surrogate key to identify your user record - most commonly there's a unique employee ID available. The only vanilla-crm alternative could be `internalemailaddress` (not mandatory in standard crm) but it carries almost the same uncertainty as `domainname` because users can have unlimited valid smtp addresses.